# How To Make Ask View Controller iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I need to make "ask for something" view controller in my iOS application. [image: Storyboard Scene]

This is storyboard. When I click start button (customised button), I need to go to "second one table view controller", select there an item and pass that data that I selected back to "hidden one view controller". Which segue should I use in storyboard, and how should I pass data in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use a `UINavigationController`.
Drag it from your Object library and drop it in your storyboard.

It should present a `UINavigationController` and its rootViewController (a simple `UIViewController`). Delete the rootViewController and use `ctrl + drag` (as if you wanted to create a new segue) to make your controller the `UINavigationController`'s `root view`.

You will have to do the same `ctrl + drag` to create a new segue from your first controller to the second one. but this time select `push` action segue.

If this is new for you, you should try this awesome course from Stanford:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550
It covers everything you need to make your app on iOS. If you don't have time, at least watch the 11th lecture viedo `11. Table View and iPad`.

Comment: How does this answer the op's question? Very misleading.

Comment: I'v got the following error:    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

Comment: Did you set the navigationController's root view to your first viewController ?

Comment: Thanks, one more, how to pass data back from second to first

Comment: You should use delegates or use a public method from the first VC called by the second VC before going back